# Oracle DB with Hibernate - Cannot determine embedded driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to run a spring application that connects to an Oracle Database using hibernate. I have included the Oracle JDBC driver, specified the URL, username, password, driver-class-name, and platform.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

### `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=OCACHEUSERDEV1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

---

### Here's a link to the JDBC driver I added to my build path.

[`ojdbc7`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)

---

### Here's the error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: If you could add more of your code, and also maybe a pic of the error would be great to give a better answer

Comment: According to documentation, the value of `spring.jpa.database-platform` should be Database enum, which would be ORACLE in your case

Comment: @GrayCygnus There isn't really any more code. It's an out-of-the-box spring boot application. Added the error message.

Comment: @jny Can you link where you saw that?

Comment: @qbolt I saw it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html.